# Extracting value from curly bracket SQL

Tags: sql, data-science, data-analysis, presto, trino

I am trying figure out how to extract a value from curly brackets in a column in Prestosql.

The field looks like,

```
rates
{"B":750}
{"B":1600}
{"B":900}
```

I want to extract the number values only in each bracket.
Also, if I want to divide that by 10 and then divide by 20 would that be easy to add into the query?

The `rates` column is of type `map(varchar, bigint)`.

Comment: To extract the numbers you can use regular expressions like: SELECT regexp_extract('{"B":750}', '\d+'). Check this link for reference: https://prestodb.github.io/docs/current/functions/regexp.html

Comment: What's the type of `rates` column? Is it varchar, JSON or something else? (You can check this with `select typeof(rates) from ... limit 1` if this is some complex expression)

Comment: @PiotrFindeisen thanks! it is varchar, bigint type what does that mean?

Comment: I am not sure I understand. Maybe include full output of `select typeof(rates) from ... limit 1` in your question.

Comment: @PiotrFindeisen the output I am getting for whhat type of rates column is 

- map(varchar, bigint)

Comment: @Chris90 thanks for providing the type information. I added an answer based on that. If you have more specific needs, please provide example expected output in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `rates` column is of type `map(varchar, bigint)`. You can use [Presto Map Functions and Operators](https://prestosql.io/docs/current/functions/map.html) on it. Examples:

```
SELECT rates['B'] FROM ... -- value under key "B"
SELECT map_values(rates) FROM ... -- all values in a map
```

See more in the [Presto documentation](https://prestosql.io/docs/current/functions/map.html).

Comment: So what if I want only the number value regardless of whatever letter or word is in that bracket? thanks!

Comment: Also, the results are coming up like [100] or [1000], how I remove these brackets from the output column?

Comment: Does your map contain always exactly one key/value pair?

Comment: Correct just one

Comment: @Chris90 you can get the only element from an array with `...[1]`, so in your case this would be `map_values(rates)[1]`.

Answer (score 1):

Use something like this, where the `regexp_extract` function pulls out the number from your string, and the `cast` function converts this from a string to a number, which you can then go on to divide by 10 etc.

```
select cast(regexp_extract(rates, '\d+') as double) / 10
from my_table
```

Comment: `double` is a number with decimal places, you could use `int` instead if you don't need decimal places.

Comment: Thanks, I tried your method. I get this error. 

 Unexpected parameters (map(varchar,bigint), varchar(3)) for function regexp_extract. Expected: regexp_extract(varchar(x), JoniRegExp) , regexp_extract(varchar(x), JoniRegExp, bigint)

Comment: try `cast(regexp_extract(json_format(JSON rates), '\d+') as double) / 10` instead